# Retrieving a list of values across databases with mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

I have 2 Java POJO files

```
class Filter Variables {
private String id;
private String name;
private List<ValueVariables> variableValues;
getters() setters()
}
```

```
class ValueVariables {
private String id;
private String valueListId;
private String value;
}
```

The database has a FK mapping between FilterVariable.id and ValueVariable.valueListId. Inserts into the table work perfectly, i have a single transaction that inserts into both tables separately. While retrieving the data using `select` and `join`, I only receive the first row from the table in the database.

Database Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filter_variables (
id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS variable_values (
id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
valueListId VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY (valueListId) REFERENCES filter_variables(id)
);
```

```
<select id="selectFilterVariableById" parameterType="java.lang.String" resultMap="FilterVariablesJoinResultMap">
    select FV.id, FV.name, VV.value, VV.valueListId
    from filter_variables as FV left outer join variable_values as VV ON FV.id=VV.valueListId
    where FV.id = #{id,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
</select>
```

The method in the interface is defined as `List<FilterVariables> selectFilterVariableById(String id);`
I understand that with 2 separate  I can store values into the two Pojo and use them, but is there any way with joins where I can retrieve multiple rows?

The result map is defined as so:

```
<resultMap id="FilterVariablesJoinResultMap" type="com.example.mybatissample.FilterVariables">
    <id column="id" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="id" />
    <result column="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
    <collection property="variableValues" ofType="com.example.mybatissample.ValueVariables">
      <id property="id" column="id"/>
      <result property="valueListId" column="valueListId"/>
      <result property="value" column="value"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

This is how the data in mysql looks like.
[image]

When a request is made from Java:

```
List<FilterVariables> vals= filterVariablesMapper.selectFilterVariableById(id);
System.out.println(vals);
System.out.println(vals.size());
```

I only get the first row

`[FilterVariables [id=b218df5c-eac1-4e01-846a-119345bb254d, name=ME, valueId=null, storageRecordType=null, values={b218df5c-eac1-4e01-846a-119345bb254d test@mailinator.com}]]`

`1`

Comment: The design is unclear, but using the same `id` for both parent object and collection elements does not make sense. `<id />` in `<collection />` should be the primary key of `variable_values`. There is `valueId` in your query, but the values are `NULL`. You didn't post the table declaration, but don't you mean `W.id valueId`, for example?

Comment: I have added the schema, please have a look. Please ignore the NULL values in valueId, they arent of importance now. Did not get your last line. @ave

Comment: Try these and see if that is what you want : 1) in the query, replace `valueId` with `W.id valueId` and 2) in the `<collection />`, replace the current `<id />` element with `<id property="id" column="valueId" />`.

Comment: the problem isnt with valueId at all, its with value and valueListId @ave Not sure on where it comes into picture. Please assume that valueId doesnt exist. I have removed it from the question altogether. Also by W i hope you mean VV

Comment: Then you must remove `<id />` from the `<collection />`. MyBatis uses it to identify collection elements and those two rows have the same `id` (because it's the primary key of `filter_variables`). Note that not having `<id />` in `<collection  />` has a performance penalty as mentioned in the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#id_.26_result).

Comment: WOW! thanks so much. Works now. I would like to have my performance at its best. Would it make sense for me to rename one of the PK id's to something else? Would that allow me to add back id to collections?

Comment: :D Renaming PK in the table is one way, but it's not necessary if you assign column alias as I suggested earlier. There also is another approach i.e. define separate result map for `ValueVariables ` and specify `columnPrefix`. See the example in the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Nested_Results_for_Collection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @ave, the solution is to either

1. Remove the  from the collection - degrades performance
2. Just rename the variable used in  - Implementation below:

The result map is now:

```
<resultMap id="FilterVariablesJoinResultMap" type="com.example.mybatissample.FilterVariables">
    <id column="id" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="id" />
    <result column="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
    <collection property="variableValues" ofType="com.example.mybatissample.ValueVariables">
      <id property="varId" column="varId"/>
      <result property="valueListId" column="valueListId"/>
      <result property="value" column="value"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

With this the results come as required.

ValueVariable is now:

```
class ValueVariables {
private String varId;
private String valueListId;
private String value;
getters() and setters()
}
```

The select query is now:

```
<select id="selectFilterVariableById" parameterType="java.lang.String" resultMap="FilterVariablesJoinResultMap">

    select FV.id, name, description, type, columnId, storageRecordType, valueId,
    operator, dbId, sharedValue, systemVariable, VV.id as varId, VV.value, VV.valueListId
    from filter_variables as FV left outer join variable_values as VV ON FV.id=VV.valueListId
    where FV.id = #{id,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
  </select>
```

Please note that VV.id is to be aliased for this to work.